# Intercept routes without tracing

Tags: apache-camel, interceptor

The application I'm working on is a middleware app that allows routing among tons of applications (mostly SOAP services).
We encountered saturation because of the automatic logs generated by Camel.

The log volume was reduced with the new interceptors. However, if a service is called inside a current route, all I got is the Request Body from the SendToEndpoint interceptor.

Given that all service calls in the application was made that way, I can not change the current routes.

Old interceptors:

```
            getContext().setTracing(true); // <--- trace every step of all routes
            interceptFrom().to("log:example");

            configureRoutes() {
            // route logic
            }
```

New interceptors:

```
            getContext().setTracing(false);
            interceptFrom("cxf:*").to("log:example");
            interceptSendToEndpoint("cxf:*").to("log:example");

            configureRoutes() {
            // route logic
            }
```

Example of a route :

```
            from("scheduler endpoint")
                .to("DAO method to find the case from database")
                .process(//First processor to call the SOAP service)
                .to("SOAP endpoint")
                .convertBodyTo(SOAP ResponseBody.class) <-- convert the MessageContentsList to SOAP response body generated from the WSDL
                .process(//Second processor to check if the response code is OK in the SOAP response body);
```

How can I implement an interceptor that allows to log also the SOAP response body ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike to use interceptors to this porpoise, I suggest you to use the EventNotifier interface, you just need to declare it as a bean in camel context and override the notify method.

See: https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/EventNotifier.html

Here is an usage example: http://camel.apache.org/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html

Note: Camel has some events that you can uss like: CamelContextCreated, ExchangeCreatedEvent, ExchangeSendingEvent, ExchangeSentEvent, ExchangeCompletedEvent, ExchangeFailedEvent, etc.